# How to do file upload in e2e AngularJS tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, file-upload, angularjs, drag-and-drop

In one of my views, I have a file upload control. It supports file uploading either via drag and drop, or via the standard file dialog opened after a button click.

How to do this in my e2e tests<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sup>1</sup> Just one of the two options will be enough

Comment: What part of functionality do you exactly need to test? Is it the correct drag'n'drop behavior or just the file upload? Is it enough to send a file (e.g., `new File()`) via AJAX?

Comment: I just need to do a file upload (with a real file), so I can continue with my other tests.

Comment: So sending a real file via AJAX would work, sending an empty file created with new File() would not.

Comment: If it helps, the file is a xml file and I have no problem with creating that file inside my testing code, if there is a way to do it.

Comment: How do you write your end-to-end tests? [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) supports [file uploads](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Does_WebDriver_support_file_uploads?).

Comment: I am using e2e testing which comes with AngularJS http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload files using Javascript blobs. This requires the FileApi, which isn't compatible with older browsers (http://caniuse.com/fileapi). But since you mentioned using drag and drop uploads, which uses the FileApi, it shouldn't matter too much.

There are two ways you can upload files using the blob API. One is very easy and the other is simply a continuation of the first.

Using Javascript, you can create a new blob with:

```
var blob = new Blob("content", contentType);
```

For example, this will create a blob object that contains the text "Hello World!".

```
var foo = new Blob("Hello World!", {type: "text/plain"});
```

---

You could also use the following method is better for non-plaintext files, such as pdf's. You have to convert the file to Base64 (you can use something like [this](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/)) and create the blob using the Base64 data.

Use this function (a slightly modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)) to create the blob.

```
function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
b64Data = b64Data.replace(/\s/g, '');
contentType = contentType || '';
sliceSize = sliceSize || 1024;

function charCodeFromCharacter(c) {
    return c.charCodeAt(0);
}

var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
var byteArrays = [];

for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
    var byteNumbers = Array.prototype.map.call(slice, charCodeFromCharacter);
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
}

var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
return blob;
}
```

For example, this will create a PDF blob object.

```
var pdf = "JVBERi0xLjQKJcfsj6IKNSAwIG9...=="; //base64 encoded file as a String
var pdfBlob = b64toBlob(pdf, "application/pdf", 1024);
```

---

After you create the blob with one of the methods above, it can be treated as a file. For example, you could put the file into a FormData object (if you're doing uploads like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/danielzen/utp7j/)):

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("uploadedFile", pdfBlob, "My PDF.pdf"*);
```

*Filename parameter only seems to work on Chrome as of now.