# File upload testing in angular js using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

We are using [ngFlow](https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow) to do file uploads in our application. We use protractor for our testing. We have multiple test case conditions to be tested like file format not supported, max size etc. What is the best way to select files using protractor? We are able to click the button to upload the file, but we don't have any control on the system file explorer. We are able to send keys to input type file but we don't know how to call submit on that as we are not a button inside of a form/ using a form.

Comment: This is how I do it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-testing/21314337#21314337

Comment: @AndresD, I did go thru your solution but we have a specific use case of using ngflow. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: Did you try sending the Enter key?

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the path of your file into your input.

```
var path = require('path');

it('should upload file', function() {
  var fileToUpload = '../path/foo.txt',
  var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
  $('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
  $('#uploadButton').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach here will be to use **superspawn** to run a batch file or any script that works on your desired operating system. You can read about superspawn here-https://www.npmjs.com/package/superspawn