# Testing upload a file to filepicker with protractor in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

In an AngularJS project I am trying to test with protractor if a file is uploaded correctly to [filepicker](http://filepicker.com/).

Filepicker `input type="file"` element is whithin a `iframe name="filepicker_dialog" id="filepicker_dialog"` so firstly is needed to *get access* to the iframe:

```
 var
     ptor = protractor.getInstance(),
     driver = ptor.driver;

 //Open iframe
 element(by.id('openIframe')).click();

 //Wait iframe is present
 browser.wait(function(){
     return element(by.id('filepicker_dialog')).isPresent();
 })
 .then(function(){
     //Switch protractor to iframe
     ptor.switchTo().frame('filepicker_dialog');
 })
```

As Selenium wiki says to upload the file some trick have to be done because...

> [You can't interact with the native OS file browser dialog directly](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3A_Does_WebDriver_support_file_uploads?)

So based on [How to upload file in angularjs e2e protractor testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21314337/1355416) answer I am setting file path on input value:

```
//Upload image
.then(function(){
    //Get image's absolute path
    var fileToUpload = '../../public/assets/img/header.jpg';
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

    //Set image's path as input (file type) value               
    driver.findElement(By.id('fileUploadInput')).sendKeys(absolutePath);

    //Submit form
    driver.findElement(By.id('fileUploadForm')).submit();

    // Switch back to Default Content
    ptor.switchTo().defaultContent();
 });
```

File seems to be uploaded inside the iframe but not to my project, the problems is that iframe is not closed and remains like this:
[image]

I contacted filepicker team and their answer was:

> So when file is uploaded all what’s happen is sending results to the original website via communication iframe or local storage.
>   If communication iframe and local storage are unavailable data sending will fail and widget will be stayed open with error message.

As they suggest problem may be that protractor *is one the iframe* so can't communicate with the main frame, despite I am doing   `ptor.switchTo().defaultContent();` to switch to main frame.

Console has only one error and not really helpful:
[image]

I almost know what happens but I don't know what else do, any advice/idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working now, as [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28834165/1355416) said I `.switchTo().defaultContent()` but I do after I `.sendKeys(absolutePath)`. Is not needed to submit the form.

Then I wait to iframe is closed ([not present](http://docsplendid.com/archives/209)).

Whole code:

```
 var
     ptor = protractor.getInstance(),
     driver = ptor.driver;

 //Open iframe
 element(by.id('openIframe')).click();

 //Wait iframe is present
 browser.wait(function(){
     return element(by.id('filepicker_dialog')).isPresent();
 })
 .then(function(){
     //Switch protractor to iframe
     ptor.switchTo().frame('filepicker_dialog');
 })
 //Upload image
 .then(function(){
    //Get image's absolute path
    var fileToUpload = '../../public/assets/img/header.jpg';
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

    //Set image's path as input (file type) value               
    driver.findElement(By.id('fileUploadInput')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
 }) 
 // Switch back to Default Content
 .then(function(){
     ptor.switchTo().defaultContent();
 })
//Wait iframe is closed
.then(function(){
    browser.wait(function(){
        var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
        element(by.id('filepicker_dialog')).isPresent()
            .then(function(present){
                deferred.fulfill(!present);
             });
        return deferred.promise;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason could be "when" you are switching to the default content - try to do it only *once the form is submitted*:

```
element(by.id('fileUploadForm')).submit().then(function() {
    browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="upload" type="file">
```

Solution:

```
var absolutePath = path.join(__dirname,'..\\..\\dash-e2e-tests\\resources\\files-cabin\\test-files\\image.png);

element(by.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys(absolutePath);
```