# Protractor - How to upload file using ng-file-upload in test case without changing code?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, protractor

> I am using https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload for file upload. I have to test it so I wrote protractor test case but it not working.

Code

```
<div class="col-lg-12 up-buttons">
     <div ng-file-select="" ng-model="files" ng-model-rejected="rejFiles" class="btn btn-default" ng-multiple="false" ng-accept="'text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'"  ng-model-rejected="rejFiles" tabindex="0">Choose file</div>
</div>
```

Test case

```
it('upload file', function(){   
  var fileToUpload = 'C:/Users/Anusha/Desktop/demo.csv';
  var absolutePath = path.resolve(fileToUpload);
  $('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
  browser.sleep(1500);
})
```

[image: testcase result]

I can upload file but it is received in **rejFiles** model instead of **files** model eventhough file format is correct one. Could anyone please suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Html

```
<div class="col-lg-12 up-buttons">
    <div ng-file-select="" ng-model="files" ng-model-rejected="rejFiles" class="btn btn-default" ng-multiple="false" ng-accept="'*.csv'"  ng-model-rejected="rejFiles" tabindex="0">Choose file</div>
</div>
```

Test case

```
var path = require('path');
var fileToUpload = file_path;
var absolutePath = path.resolve(fileToUpload);
element.all(by.css('input[type="file"]')).then(function(items) {
  items[0].sendKeys(absolutePath);
});
browser.sleep(500);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with **runtime DOM element change**. So we can get element by element's runtime changed property and for file uploading case, DOM changes a property with **'input[type="file"]'**.No matter if there is `input` tag for uploading element.

```
element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePathOfFile);
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for some time but found that **I had to trigger a click on the `ngf-select` element before trying to `sendKeys`.**

```
it('upload file', function(){
  var fileToUpload = 'C:/Users/Anusha/Desktop/demo.csv';
  var absolutePath = path.resolve(fileToUpload);
  var button = element(by.css('[ng-file-select]');
  button.click();
  var input = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
  input.sendKeys(absolutePath);
});
```

The input is added by ng-file-upload at the bottom of the page after the `ngf-select` directive button is clicked.

Also, I was able to use relative paths (relative to the location of the spec file) for the file like this:

```
it('upload file', function(){
  var path = require('path');
  var fileToUpload = '../demo.csv';
  var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
  var button = element(by.css('[ng-file-select]');
  button.click();
  var input = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
  input.sendKeys(absolutePath);
});
```

This assumes you have run `npm install path --save-dev`.

*This is using Protractor 2.0.0 and ng-file-upload 4.0.4*

Answer (score 0):

Absolute path has helped me:

```
var fileToUpload = 'D:/file.csv';
var absolutePath = path.resolve(fileToUpload);
$('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
element(by.css('#doUpload')).click();
```

(Also discuessed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing))

Comment: I have tried it. It is working but my button will show only ng-model="files" receives file. It is not working as for my requirement

Comment: Here file is taking but it is putting file in rejFiles model not in files model