# Are you able to upload a file

Tags: angularjs, protractor

[image]

I have a test that I would like to upload pictures to a website that uses the defaulted OS upload modal. After I click upload I cannot access the upload screen.  Is there a way around it?  I saw online that it looked like there was but I had no idea how to implement what they were saying.

```
element(By.xpath("//div[@id='ngdialog28']/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/span")).click()
element(By.css("input[type=\"file\"]")).click();
element(By.css("input[type=\"file\"]")).clear();
element(By.css("input[type=\"file\"]")).sendKeys("C:\\ProgramData\\MeetingMatrix International\\MeetingMatrix 2010\\MMIDEMO\\Setups\\Test.mms");
```

Comment: @Sergio I am updating a screenshot of what I mean, sorry I am pre-coffee

Comment: @Sergio before you -1 please ask to clarify, thanks.

Comment: Can't you just set the value of that file input (therefore sidestepping all this modal window access stuff)?

Comment: @Sergio I've tried that, or so I thought, I'm new to Angularjs and Protractor from what I've seen online its tricky and i have not found any code examples to go with it, at least that work for me. I am updating with the code I tried.

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21314337/125816

Comment: @Sergio hmmm I dont know how I missed that bottom part as I reviewed that question earlier.  I will give that a try, fingers crossed.

Comment: @Sergio the first one did not, I am checking out the bottom answer now, I had a no visible element issue to deal with first, just fixed that.

Comment: @Sergio The first did work I had to remove the last line of code, fantastic ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer below came from a previous post I had overlooked. 
Here is the code:

```js
var path = require('path');

var fileToUpload = 'Put the path here',
  absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

$('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
```