# Force browser to open a new tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, automation, protractor

I have an app that performs an upload.  I cannot seem to get the file system pop up to close. It does not mess up the test, it keeps running in the background but the odd chance that I want to watch the test a quarter of the screen is covered.  So I figure a fix to this problem would just be force the rest of the test to complete in a new tab.  I have no idea how to do this.

Here is my upload code:

```
var uploadPathLink = element(by.css('button.btn.btn-select'));
var path = require('path');
//the file to upload
fileToUpload,
//this is variable that inserts the path to find file to upload
absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
//inserts the path
uploadPathLink.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Related to this question: [Upload modal will not close after filepath is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527557/upload-modal-will-not-close-after-filepath-is-sent)

Comment: @JeffC  It is very similar however that is using a dated version of Protractor syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open a new tab, pass in the commands that you usually do using keyboard (CONTROL+T). Here's one sample of it -

```
element(by.tagName('html')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "t")); //If you are using MAC then replace CONTROL with COMMAND
//element can be any element in your DOM
```

Later you can switch to the new tab using `getWindowHandle()`. Hope this helps.