# Automate file uploading functionality using protractor

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor

How to automate file uploading functionality using protractor?

Comment: Please specify you question. What are system window and files you need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload file in angularjs e2e protractor testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking how to upload a file to your app, correct?  if so this code works:

```js
var path = require('path');
//the file to upload
var fileToUpload = 'C:\\your file path',
  //this is variable that inserts the path to find file to upload
  absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
//inserts the path
$('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
```