# Protractor E2E test of ng-file-upload

Tags: testing, jasmine, protractor, ng-file-upload

How to E2E test a ng-file-upload?

```
<div id="fileBTSToUpload"  ngf-drop ngf-select ng-model="fileBTS"  class="drop-box" ngf-accept="'.txt'" ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'"> Drag and Drop here
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, with `Protractor` alone, you cannot do the actual drag and drop of a file to a designated are on a page. And, another problem is that if you manage to open the browser's upload dialog window, you would not be able to control it via `Protractor`/`WebDriverJS`.

A common approach is to find the `input` element with `type="file"` and send keys to it containing the *absolute path to the file you want to upload*. The `input` has to be on the page for upload to work, though commonly the `input` is hidden and you would need to make it visible in order to perform "send keys". See sample solutions here:

- [How to upload file in angularjs e2e protractor testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing)

Answer (score -2):

Set your Protractor version to "1.6.1" and ng-file-upload to "9.0.1". To do these, act as follows:
`npm install protractor@1.6.1`

Edit file:    bower.json and set the version:

```
"ng-file-upload": "~9.0.1",
```

And then execute the following:

```
bower install
```

The Angular code must also contains a button in it to work:

```
<div id="fileBTSToUpload"  ngf-drop ngf-select ng-model="fileBTS"  class="drop-box" ngf-accept="'.txt'" ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'"> Drag and Drop
        </div>

        <button id="btn2" ng-click="uploadFileToUrl(fileBTS, btsUrl);">upload</button>
```

The Jasmine code for E2E testing is as follows:

```
it('a sample test...',function(){
//Assemble
browser.get('/the_page_url');
//Act
var fileToUpload = './some-file.csv';
var path = require('path');
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname,fileToUpload);
var input = element(by.css('input[type=file]'));
input.sendKeys(absolutePath);
element(by.id('btn2')).click();
browser.waitForAngular();  
//Assert
expect(2).toEqual(2);
//browser.sleep(5000);
//browser.pause();  
});
```

And for path to be installed, do this:

```
npm install path
```

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because of the protractor 1.6.1 installation step. Not sure why you suggest to use a version that is more than a year old and 2 stable versions behind the current..Though, I have to agree, the middle part where you send the keys to the input is correct.