# Protractor can't find file to upload on Firefox

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, protractor

I want to test file uploading with this code, which was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing) :

```
var path = require('path');    

var fileToUpload = '..\\..\\files\\avatarPicture.jpg';
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

var fileElem = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));

browser.executeScript(
  "arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px'; arguments[0].style.opacity = 1", fileElem.getWebElement());

browser.executeAsyncScript(function(callback) {
   document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').style.display = 'inline';
   callback();
   });

   $('input[type="file"]').clear().sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

and there is a WebDriverError:

```
Failed: File not found: C:\works\project\files\avatarPicture.jpg
```

- I already checked the path - it is correct. I can easily open file from command line
- I try to use both backslashes and slashes. There is still same error.
- WebDriver version: gecko v0.17.0
- Windows 10 Pro
- Everything is working on Chrome, **but I need a solution for Firefox**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing/21314337#21314337

Comment: @VenuDuggireddy ok, so far I know that it is Firefox issue, the file is visible on, for example, Chrome, but still Firefox cannot find that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fileElem.clear().then(function() {
    fileElem.sendKeys(absolutePath);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as in this [Bug 858](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/858#issuecomment-323157157) workaround