# How to upload file using protractor

Tags: file-upload, protractor

I am trying to upload image, when i click on upload image button then it displays all images but i am failed to select image.

This is the HTML code, please suggest me a solution.

```
<div class="uploadimg clearfix" ng-show="member.data.imageType != 'avatar'">
   <div ng-model="member.data.image" name="image" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles,'user')" class="button ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
      <img ng-src="/public/images/uploadimg-img.jpg" src="/public/images/uploadimg-img.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="uploadingsecpop ng-hide" ng-show="member.data.image &amp;&amp; member.data.imageType == 'image'">
      <img class="thumb" src="/public/images/" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing) for the similar issue and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = require('path');
var fileToUpload = "F://images/f2.jpg";
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
element(&%#LOCATOR&^#%).sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Comment: replace `&%#LOCATOR&^#%` with `element(by.css('div.uploadimg.clearfix'));`

Comment: thanks for your comments, can you explain about "_dirname", what is that?

Comment: It is used to denote the directory name. Please mark the answer as correct. If the solution helped you.

Comment: it's not working for me, please suggest another way.