# Protractor - Uploading a Document using a Modal

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing, end-to-end

I am currently using protractor to validate a user's walk through a Web App. To proceed (buttons are disabled until an action is performed) a user must upload a document, which then enables buttons to be pressed and would then proceed with the process.

In my local code I have a folder that contains the document needed to be uploaded to proceed. However, when I am interacting with the web app via protractor, I am struggling with getting it uploaded.

As it works now:

1. Click link to upload doc
2. Modal is displayed with Browse button to select 
   ([Modal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLSq9.png))
3. Browse button must be used to browse for the file - cannot insert into 'text box'
4. Select a date using calendar tool
5. Submit button then becomes active
6. Click Submit and can proceed through app process

I have attempted the solution here:
[How to upload file in angularjs e2e protractor testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing/21314337)
, but the issue is that the 'text area' to insert the path into returns an 'Invalid Element State Error' - I cannot simply insert the path into the box as the solution above seems to suggest.

Bottom line is I need to upload this document while necessarily using the browse button, but I cannot use protractor to manipulate the local dialogue box used to browse the machine.

My code:

```js
it('should upload the example doc', function() {
  var path = require('path');
  var fileToUpload = 'path/path/path/',
    absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
  page.findInput().sendKeys(absolutePath);
  browser.sleep(3000);
  expect(page.submitBtnClick());
});
```

Thoughts?

Comment: what is findInput() doing? Does it locate the input element? If you look at your Modal does it contain a hidden <input> field to upload a document. Thats the element you need to do a sendKeys to.

Comment: paste the html of the modal so I can see...

Comment: Hi Simon - thanks for the response.
findInput() is simply locating the input element. 

I think you are right in that in the modal there is a hidden <input> field...I am unable to share the html b/c of the sensitive nature of the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer Found Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206851/protractor-unable-to-handle-windows-based-popup-to-browse-and-upload-a-file-usi?rq=1)

functioning code below:

```ts
uploadDoc() {
return browser.findElement(by.css('input[type=file]')).sendKeys('full/path/of/the file/with.extension');
}
```