# How to handle windows file upload using protractor and typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, file-upload, protractor, ng-file-upload

I am clicking on a upload button which opens up a windows file selector. I am not able to write the path to a file in that File Selector dialog using protractor.

I tried copying the text to the clipboard and pasting the same to File Upload by passing ctrl+v keypress in protractor. Able to copy the text but paste is not working.

Now I have also used robot-js but not helping me 
Any idea how can we do this in protractor?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if libraries for this exist but I would recommend to just simulate the file upload since protractor is made for testing in the browser. => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing
just a thought.

Comment: i have already tried this

Comment: The question that Silvan referenced is the only way to upload a file in protractor. If this isn't working for you create a new question with the errors you get from using that method so we can help you with that.

Comment: after this action element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);  -it is taking file in input control, but after this action element(by.id('uploadButton')).click(); -it is again opening window file dialog , so i am thinking , how to enter path in opened window dialog and for press enter i have used this browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);

Answer (score 0):

Send keys to the input element with your file path, it will do the same flow without opening the windows file pop up