# Unable to handle Ubuntu Based popup to browse and upload a image using Protractor

Tags: angular, image, typescript, file-upload, protractor

[image]Automating angular 2+ based web application locally using protractor & jasmine framework

Scenario: Click on Add subject button > click on subject icon > Operating system based popup(model box) come > select the file > Click on open button > attached image name should be display

But failed to select the file
Refereed many of the post but all the solution comes with upload button
for example "[How to upload file in angularjs e2e protractor testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing/21314337#21314337)" but no luck
I attached screenshot for reference...Any help will be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing/21314337#21314337

Comment: i already tried the mentioned link but no luck bcz unable to see the selected file name