# using protractor to do selenium automation test with windows upload file popup

Tags: selenium-webdriver, file-upload, protractor

Right now, i am doing an UIveri5 automation test. when clicking the button, windows file system dialog pop up, i would like to know how can i input the file that i want to upload and click the upload button to go back to the web page. 
I have try the ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing/21314337#21314337), but all the ways didn't work. if someone know about this situation, please give me some advises, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

File upload is handled by the selenium/webdiver and happens the same way in every selenium-based framework - locate the input of type file and enter the path to the file. Then click the submit button. 
You can use uiveri5 control locators to find the upload control and just chain with `by.css('input[type="file"])` to locate the input. Locate the submit button in a similar way.