# How to implement AutoIt In Protractor

Tags: angular, automation, protractor

In Our Application we have a html with only an upload button. After clicking on the upload button, there will be a windows popup to browse the file. How can we handle this with protractor? Please demonstrate the use of Auto It. Please help with the code which needs to be integrated.

Upload

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload file in angularjs e2e protractor testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing)