# How to execute a command in javascript to upload files to application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

Am working on protractor framework and I need to upload files to the application using a script.I know how to do it in java but no idea in javascript. Can someone please help me on this:

Java code :

```
public static void fileUpload(String script, String filePath) {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("script " + script + " " + filePath);

    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    try {
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305298/how-to-upload-file-in-angularjs-e2e-protractor-testing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant by script here. Using sendkeys with upload input element should work in protractor.

like :
   `var path = require('path');
   var fileToUpload = '../test-resources/filetoupload'; //(the example relative path of the file )
   var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
   element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
   uploadButton().click();`

Comment: Script is a file that contains set of instructions like  enter the path in the window popup ,selects the file and hits enter to upload.